# How do I undo this splitting of text into columns?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, text-formatting

I've received an ODT file, where the text, intended to have usual page-wide layout appears to be split in two columns. If I copy the text and paste as plain text, I get this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

But in LibreOffice Writer it looks instead like this:

[image: screenshot of the problem]

I've tried looking into *Format*->*Page*->*Columns*, but there I have *Columns* spinbox read `1`, so there the setting is single-column layout. Apparently, there's more than one way to have two columns.

What is the feature this document is using? How do I turn it off so that the document became single-column?

Comment: you can always copy&paste without the formating (just the text) using ctrl+alt+v if thats what you want to acomplish

Comment: @weberik what I want to accomplish is to remove the splitting from the document.

Comment: i currently dont have libreoffice at hand to test it myself, but i think you can just move this small triangles in the ruler between the page and the menu bar. try moving it with the mouse completely to the left.

Comment: @weberik at least one letter of each line remains in the shrunk column, so this isn't a solution.

Comment: i now got to my linux pc (with writer installed) and tested it. i think you have 2 different formating concepts messing with your layout. 1. the colums (can be set to 1 like you described) and those triangles to set the indent. the indent is in the paragraph formating, the columns in the page/document. try setting both to the minimum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, there appears to indeed be *two* ways to double the number of columns:

1. Format->Page->Columns
2. Format->Columns

Set `2` in one, you'll get two columns. Set `2` in both, and you have four(!).

Well. Not so simple. In this particular file it was this way: Format->Page->Columns dialog had 1 column set, while Format->Columns had 2. When I changed the former to 2, I got 4 columns in the document. When I made both 1, I got what I wanted.

But if I create a *new* document, these dialogs appear to be synchronized and don't have such strange behavior.

Comment: I have this identical problem, but there is no Format > Columns in my Libre Office so I can't do [2]. Format > Page > Columns already says '1'. Where do I find Format > Columns?

Comment: @PeterFlynn in LibreOffice 6.2.4.2 Writer on Linux I have the following _Format_ menu, with the _Columns_ option selected: https://i.imgur.com/EYIyPwA.png